# AWS- Build a Modern Web Application(Mythical Mysfits)-Error with Docker Image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-fargate

I am new in the area of network and server management with zero experience. I am trying to learn from the tutorial "MythicalMysfits" from AWS. The other post helped and I updated pip to pip3, but now I am stuck due to a different error on Module 2B- Step1 - A, https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-modern-app-fargate-lambda-dynamodb-python/module-two/ . After running the docker command,

```
docker build . -t REPLACE_ME_AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.REPLACE_ME_REGION.amazonaws.com/mythicalmysfits/service:latest
```

I am still getting error of insufficient space, I tried clearing cache with cmd- sudo yum clean cache, but still error persists-

```
Need to get 337 MB of archives. 
After this operation, 1111 MB of additional disk space will be used. 
E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/. 
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y python3-pip python-dev build-essential.' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Actually after some research and hit and trial I was able to successfully solve the problem of space , by running below command-

```
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
docker rm -v $(docker ps -qa)
```

or

```
docker container prune
```